# Converting Ruby to Python

Tags: python, ruby, regex

I'm trying to convert my ruby script to python. I'm not very familiar with python so I am getting a `TypeError`.

#### printer.rb

```
Lease = Struct.new(:property, :renter)
lease_list = []

File.open('input.txt').readlines.each do |line|
  p, r = line.split(' - ')
  lease_list << Lease.new(p.tr('#', ''), r)
end

# sort by decimal value
lease_list.sort_by { |m| m.property.scan(/\d+/)[0].to_i }.each do |lease|
  puts "\##{lease.property} - #{lease.renter}"
end
```

#### printer.py

```
import re

class Lease:
  def __init__(self, renter=None, unit=None):
    self.renter = renter
    self.property = unit

lease_list = []
import sys
lines = open('input.txt', 'r')
for line in lines:
    l, m = line.split(' - ')
    lease_list.append(Lease(l,m))
lines.close()

print lease_list.sort(key=lambda lease: re.split(r"\d+", lease.property))
```

#### python error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "printer.py", line 16, in
<module>
    print lease_list.sort(key=lambda str: re.split(r"\d+", str))   File "printer.py", line 16, in <lambda>
    print lease_list.sort(key=lambda str: re.split(r"\d+", str))   File
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py",
line 171, in split
    return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit) TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: That's not a syntax error, it's a `TypeError`. A syntax error shows up as `SyntaxError`. And yes, there is a significant difference.

Comment: @AvinashRaj In the sort I am trying to find the decimal value the unit attribute and sort by that

Comment: replace `lease.unit` with `lease.property` on the last line

Comment: Now that you've changed the code, the error doesn't make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
print lease_list.sort(key=lambda str: re.split(r"\d+", str))
```

The `str` name **[edit: see Question edit history]**, *which you generally shouldn't use as a name, even as throwaways*) which is assigned values contained in your list and consequently passed to `re.split()` *is an object of type `Lease`*:

```
lease_list.append(Lease(l,m))
```

This isn't accepted as an argument to `re.split` it likes munching on `str`s. hence the *`TypeError`*. `Lease` has two attributes which are `str`s after the `line.split(' - ')`:

```
self.renter = renter
self.property = unit
```

Use one of these in `re.split()` (whichever is required for your use-case) with:

```
print lease_list.sort(key=lambda obj: re.split(r"\d+", obj.renter))
```

or:

```
print lease_list.sort(key=lambda obj: re.split(r"\d+", obj.property))
```

Forgot to mention, sorting a `list` with `list.sort` will return `None` since it sorts the list *in place*, printing the value here has no use.

Comment: It prints out `None`

Comment: Ah yes, `sort` sorts *in place*, returning `None`. The list you passed in is sorted, though.